# auditd keeps writing to my disk

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, plesk

`auditd -n` keeps writing and using resources for the stuff below. What is it, and is it necessary for this script to be constantly writing stuff?

I am running Cenots 7 and Plex Onyx...if it is not needed I would really like to uninstall it.

```
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1487879713.783:1316): table=filter family=2 entries=52
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1487879713.783:1316): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=21ff8a0 items=0 ppid=18408 pid=18469 auid=10000 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=tty1 ses=4 comm="ip$
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1487879713.790:1317): table=filter family=10 entries=52
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1487879713.790:1317): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=29 a2=40 a3=190ce50 items=0 ppid=18408 pid=18470 auid=10000 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=tty1 ses=4 comm="i$
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1487879713.795:1318): table=filter family=2 entries=66
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1487879713.795:1318): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=0 a2=40 a3=a75050 items=0 ppid=18408 pid=18471 auid=10000 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=tty1 ses=4 comm="ipt$
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1487879713.802:1319): table=filter family=2 entries=67
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1487879713.802:1319): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=0 a2=40 a3=b74500 items=0 ppid=18408 pid=18472 auid=10000 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=tty1 ses=4 comm="ipt$
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1487879713.810:1320): table=filter family=2 entries=68
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1487879713.810:1320): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=0 a2=40 a3=18db680 items=0 ppid=18408 pid=18473 auid=10000 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=tty1 ses=4 comm="ip$
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1487879713.817:1321): table=filter family=10 entries=66
```

Comment: You cut off the interesting parts of each line. Remember that you should not use the `nano` editor.

Comment: "auditd is the userspace component to the Linux Auditing System. It's responsible for writing audit records to the disk. " - per `man auditd`. You might want to read up a bit on auditd, but if this is causing major issues, `sudo systemctl disable audit && sudo systemctl stop audit` should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is it

The auditd program is the userspace component to the Linux Auditing System. It's responsible for writing audit records to the disk.

> it necessary for this script to be constantly writing stuff

That's the way it has been configured.

> ..if it is not needed I would really like to uninstall it

I use it YMMV.

It would probably be a good idea if you read up on the Linux Audit system and made your own decisions about whether you need it or not.